# How can I set today as my datepicker default value?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I would like to set my datepicker default value to today:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.js-date').datepicker({
          "setDate": new Date(),
          "autoclose": true
     });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="js-date form-control" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$('.js-date').datepicker({
  "autoclose": true
}).datepicker("setDate",'now');
```

**Working demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-date').datepicker({
    "autoclose": true
  }).datepicker("setDate",'now');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="js-date form-control" />
```